# How do I use MSBuild to build solutions programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, msbuild

I have some VS solutions that I would like to build from within another VS project. I have looked at the MS documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-api?view=vs-2022) but I'd like to have an example. I'm actually stuck on preparing the BuildRequestData which is needed for the BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build() method.

```
void MethodThatDoesNotDirectlyCallMSBuild()
{
    var instance = MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances().OrderByDescending(
        instance => instance.Version).First();

    // Register a specific instance of MSBuild
    MSBuildLocator.RegisterInstance(instance);
    MethodThatCallsMSBuild(instance);
}

void MethodThatCallsMSBuild(VisualStudioInstance instance)
{
    BuildParameters parameters = new BuildParameters(new ProjectCollection())
    {
        Loggers = new ILogger[] { new ConsoleLogger() }
    };

    Project p = new Project("X:\\Drivers\\Dsp\\Dsp.sln");
    // Code that uses the MSBuild type

    BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(
        parameters,
        new BuildRequestData(p, 

}
```

I've tried searching but only found old examples. I also tried using the same powershell scripts I use to execute Git commands but I cannot get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you just want to build a set of solution files, you don't need to embed MSBuild in an application. You can write an MSBuild file that invokes the `MSBuild` task on a set of solutions. Or write a PowerShell script that loops and executes MSBuild for each solution.

Comment: Thank you. I went back to trying PowerShell and managed to figure it out using the correct syntax to run an exe.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working using PowerShell. This is .NET 7

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;

var msBuildPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\MSBuild\\Current\\Bin";
var projectFileName = "X:\\Drivers\\Dsp\\Dsp.sln";

using var powershell = PowerShell.Create();
powershell.AddScript($"& '{msBuildPath}.\\msbuild.exe' {projectFileName}  -t:rebuild -property:Configuration=Debug");
Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
foreach (var outputItem in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(outputItem);
}
```

Comment: You may want to consider updating your PowerShell script to use vswhere to [find MSBuild](https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere/wiki/Find-MSBuild), instead of hard coding the `2022\Community` path.